# Finitely Presented Objects in The Category of Quasi-Coherent Sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am looking for a text on finitely presented objects in Qco(x), the category of quasi coherent sheaves on a scheme X.  Is there some good properties for these sheaves like for finitely presented modules over a ring. For a finitely presented module F we know that if we have an epic morphism $N\to F\to 0$, hen there is a finitely generated submodule N’ of N  and an induced morphism $N’\to F\to$.  Can we say the same thing for quasi-coherent sheaves? Also one cn prove that the submodule A of a module B is pure iff the induced map $ Hom(F,B)\to Hom(F,B/A)$  be surjective for all finitely presented R-modules F. 
One can consider three different definitions of a finitely presented quasi-coherent sheaf.
(i) A globally finitely presented sheaf is one that can be written as the cokernel of a morphism
of two finite coproducts of the structure sheaf.

(ii) A locally finitely presented sheaf is one that can be locally written as such a cokernel.

(iii) A finitely presented sheaf is one satisfying the categorical property. F is f.p. if $ Hom(F,-)$
Preserves direct limits.. This makes sense in both Qco(X) and Mod(X) so we will specify the ambient category.

And we know that 
Proposition 75. Let X be a concentrated scheme and F a quasi-coherent sheaf. Then F is
finitely presented in Qco(X) if and only if it is locally finitely presented.[Murfet Homepage, Modules over a scheme].

Comment: (i) is definitely the "wrong" condition, and (ii) and (iii) turn out to be equivalent (either by your quote of Murfet's notes, but it also follows directly from the results in EGA I (1970), Section 6.9. One really needs concentrated schemes here: In general (ii) => (iii), but (iii) => (ii) is equivalent(!) to being concentrated. // You should make your question more precise. What do you want to know about f.p. qc modules? Work with (ii) and and use the affine case.

Comment: Unless $X$ satisfies further properties, there are few finitely presented objects. The category of quasi-coherent sheaves is a Grothendieck category. It is locally presentable, but usually not locally finitely presentable.

Answer (score 1):

Acctually I want to find a good reference in finiteness conditions of quasi coherent sheaves, firstly. Also I am going to know what is the relation between finitely presented objects and pure sequences.

Comment: excuse me, I couldn't find any key related to comments.

Comment: If you know German, I can send you diploma thesis (you can find my mail in the profile). There is a section about finiteness conditions.

Comment: Thank you Martin, for your comments. Unfortunately I don't know German. 